# Error installing psycopg2: pg_config executable not found

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

I want to connect my Django application to an Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL database.

1. Do I need psycopg2 installed? (I think yes)
2. How do I install pyscopg2 in a way that doesn't require an entire postgres db install.

The error when installing psycopg2 now is this:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I'm on CentOS7.

I tried:

```
$ yum install postgresql-libs
$ yum install python-psycopg2
```

These packages installed, but I still get the same error on trying to pip install pyscopg2 after.

Comment: Which operating system? You need the postgresql-client development library for your platform

Comment: I added it to the question, CentOS7

Comment: Solution in the duplicate target: `sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: and yes, psycopg2 is **the** preferred client library to connect to PostgreSQL dbs (including RDS).

Comment: Yes, that works. And now I don't have a postgres database running right?

Comment: well, you can check your `ps aux|grep postgres`, never too sure about CentOS

Comment: I checked, and no postgres was running, so I guess now the bare minimal is installed, to get psychopg2 installed. thanks!